# AWK: Comparing two different columns in two files

Tags: awk

I have these two files

File1:

```
9 8 6 8 5 2
2 1 7 0 6 1
3 2 3 4 4 6
```

File2: (which has over 4 million lines)

```
MN 1 0
JK 2 0
AL 3 90
CA 4 83
MK 5 54
HI 6 490
```

I want to compare field 6 of file1, and compare field 2 of file 2.  If they match, then put field 3 of file2 at the end of file1
I've looked at other solutions but I can't get it to work correctly.

Desired output:

```
9 8 6 8 5 2 0
2 1 7 0 6 1 0
3 2 3 4 4 6 490
```

My attempt:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$2;next}a[$6]{print $0,a[$6]}' file2 file1
```

program just hangs after that.

Comment: Your attempt does not "hang" for me.  Although it does not produce the desired answer, it runs to completion.

Comment: How long is `file1`? Also, based on the example input it looks like `file2` is sorted by field 2, is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print all lines in file1 with match if available:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;next;} {print $0,a[$6];}' file2 file1
9 8 6 8 5 2 0
2 1 7 0 6 1 0
3 2 3 4 4 6 490
```

To print only the lines that have a match:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next} $6 in a {print $0,a[$6]}' file2 file1
9 8 6 8 5 2 0
2 1 7 0 6 1 0
3 2 3 4 4 6 490
```

Note that I replaced `a[$2]=$2` with `a[$2]=$3` and changed the test `a[$6]` (which is false if the value is zero) to `$6 in a`.

Comment: Wonder why this has been downvoted – it produces the desired output with minimal changes to the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Your own attempt basically has two bugs as seen in @John1024's answer:

1. You use field 2 as both key and value in `a`, where you should be storing field 3 as the value (since you want to keep it for later), i.e., it should be `a[$2] = $3`.
2. The test `a[$6]` is false when the value in `a` is zero, even if it exists. The correct test is `$6 in a`.

Hence:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$2]=$3; next } $6 in a {print $0, a[$6] }' file2 file1
```

However, there might be better approaches, but it is not clear from your specifications. For instance, you say that `file2` has over 4 million lines, but it is unknown if there are also that many *unique* values for field 2. If yes, then `a` will also have that many entries in memory. And, you don't specify how long `file1` is, or if its order must be preserved for output, or if every line (even without matches in `file2`) should be output.

If it is the case that `file1` has many fewer lines than `file2` has unique values for field 2, and only matching lines need to be output, and order does not need to be preserved, then you might wish to read `file1` first…

Comment: Hi Arkku.  file2's fields are all unique.  It's numbers 1 to 4 million.  All lines in file1 will show in output because there will always be a match.